# R: element-wise matrix division

Tags: r, performance, matrix

Given two numeric matrices `A` and `B` of the same dimension. What's the best way for element-wise division: `A[i,j] / B[i,j]`? I know it is possible to do using double `for` loops. But I want the most efficient way.

**Edit:** When there is a `B[i,j] == 0` it will have to be `A[i,j] <- 0`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your matrices are `A` and `B`, you can just use `A / B`.

```
A <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4

B <- matrix((1:4) * 2, 2, 2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    6
#[2,]    4    8

C <- A / B
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  0.5  0.5
#[2,]  0.5  0.5
```

---

> When there is a `B[i,j] == 0` it will have to be `A[i,j] <- 0`.

In case you have 0 elements in `B`, you may get `NaN`, `Inf` or `-Inf`, depending on its counterpart in `A`.

```
0 / 0
# NA

1 / 0
# Inf

-1 / 0
# -Inf
```

All these are not finite. If you want to replace them with 0, simply do:

```
C <- A / B
C[!is.finite(C)] <- 0
```

---

It is difficult to remember how R treats `NA`, `NaN`, `Inf` and `-Inf`. You can read `?is.finite` and `?NA` for general info. Here I will give a simple test.

```
x <- c(NA, NaN, Inf, -Inf)

is.finite(x)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

is.infinite(x)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

is.na(x)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

is.nan(x)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Note, `is.infinite` is not the inverse of `is.finite`, but the inverse of `is.na`. That is why I have used `!is.finite`.

Comment: Element-wise arithmetic is also well-defined for data frames of the same size. Here is an example Q & A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52538012/4891738.