# element-wise percentage change between two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames with equal number of matching columns and rows. For example:

```
df.2010 <- data.frame(col1 = c("Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia"), col2 = 10, col3 = 20, col4 = 30)

df.2017 <- data.frame(col1 = c("Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia"), col2 = 20, col3 = 25, col4 = 90)

df.2010
                  col1 col2 col3 col4
1          Connecticut   10   20   30
2             Delaware   10   20   30
3 District of Columbia   10   20   30
4              Florida   10   20   30
5              Georgia   10   20   30

df.2017
                  col1 col2 col3 col4
1          Connecticut   20   25   90
2             Delaware   20   25   90
3 District of Columbia   20   25   90
4              Florida   20   25   90
5              Georgia   20   25   90
```

I need to create a new data frame with percent change from `df.2010` to `df.2017` for each value.

Expected Result:

```
                  col1 col2 col3 col4
1          Connecticut  100   25  200
2             Delaware  100   25  200
3 District of Columbia  100   25  200
4              Florida  100   25  200
5              Georgia  100   25  200
```

The conceptual function would be:

```
# args:
#  x: original amount
#  y: new amount
percent.change <- function(x,y) {
  ((y-x)/x)*100
}
```

I've done some research on the `*apply` function family as well as `for` loops, but I'm not familiar enough with R to get to where I need to be! Especially while preserving the values in `col1` (i.e. State names). Can anybody help me?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Element-wise arithmetic is well-defined for data frames **of the same size**. So the percentage change can be conveniently computed from

```
## remove `col1` as it is not numeric
100 * (df.2017[-1] - df.2010[-1]) / df.2010[-1]
```

The following adds `col1` back

```
data.frame(df.2017[1], 100 * (df.2017[-1] - df.2010[-1]) / df.2010[-1])
```

Comment: See `?groupGeneric` for more on S3 group generic functions. `Ops.data.frame` ("data.frame" method for `Ops`) is responsible for arithmetic between data frames.